# Select first DIV to remove its double border

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to find a way to skip the first element that are dynamically generated (div class="Title") within the (div class="MyList") class. I've tried with `:first-child` and `:first-of-type` but no luck. Basically, I'm trying to remove the double border for the first Title element. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

HTML

```
<div class="MyList">   
   <div class="Title">
      <h3></h3> 
   </div>
   <div class="List"></div>
   <div class="List"></div>
   <div class="List"></div>
   <div class="List"></div>
   <div class="Title">
      <h3></h3> 
   </div>
   <div class="List"></div>
   <div class="List"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.MyList > :first-child{
   border-top:none;
}

.Title {
    text-align: center; 
    border-left-width:15px; 
    border-bottom-width:5px;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.Title:before {
    content: '';
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.Title  h3 { padding: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2QLY/

You need to also override the `:before` code you are applying to the Title element:

```
.MyList > :first-child {
   border-top:none;
}

.MyList > :first-child:before {
    border-top: none;
}
```